Куда теряется "слеш" при переходе на главную?
Есть сайт на php простенький, логинимся кидает в https://lk..ru/main/lic/ всё окей всё работает, но если я залогиненый открываю https://lk..ru то должен открыться так же личный кабинет, но вместо этого открывается в адресной строке так https://lk.***.rumain/lic , то есть не хватает слеша в ссылке.
Есть такой htaccess в корне:
RewriteEngine On

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


Причём тут слеш на главной (да ещё и "при переходе на главную"), если у тебя речь о кривом редиректе? Вот как ты сделал редирект с морды на ЛК, там и ищи где потерял слеш

Не я писал код, а индекс вот такой: 

Жуть :) Пропиши полный адрес с протоколом. См https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php https://i.imgur.com/W0STBlc.jpeg

Подскажите как правильно написать, пробовал и с адресом и так и сяк не выходит, если с адресом то в строке браузера добавляется ещё один адрес...

Это уже другой вопрос. Но см в мануале. Я даже пример заскриншотил,.
